# Magento 2 Collection path wrong but still module is working and saving the data,how possible?

Tags: magento2, collection

I am developing a custom module to save data in custom table. I have created model and `resourcemodel` classes and also `collection.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\test;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * Define model & resource model
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            'Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Test',
            'Vendorname\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Test'
        );
    }
}
```

but I got strange when I forgot to gave the correct path in same file .
and it was the below
 `namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel;` (test folder was forgot), but code was working properly and was able to save the data.

Can anybody share how is the possible if namespace is wrong then why code is working?

Comment: This sounds interesting :P

Comment: Did you checked in your collection file which was generated folder?

Comment: @RohanHapani ,I was not checked that things but ultemetly code should not work.

Comment: I'm sure about that. Go to generated folder and find your collection file. At there, add wrong file path and clean cache. It will return error log.

Comment: @RohanHapani,but I am deleting generated folder data every time when do any changes and still this is working.

Comment: @RohanHapani,you can check it your end by creating  custom module.